# Открыть консоль из динамического кода C#

Tags: c#

Имеется вот такой вот код, который динамически компилирует сборку:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"CompilerVersion", "v4.0"}
            };

        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
        {
            IncludeDebugInformation = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");

        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы после компиляции открылась консоль с программой, код которой я компилирую динамически?
Знаю, что можно указать параметр OutputAssembly, и потом открыть скомпилированный файл. Но я не хочу с ним в дальнейшем работать, то есть использую параметр GenerateInMemory = true.

Comment: Вы поставили себе сложную задачу, я не думаю, что есть прямой путь запустить assembly как _новый_ процесс. Возможно, вам подойдёт вот что: (1) сериализировать полученную сборку в массив байт, (2) заранее подготовить вспомогательную консольную программу, которая стартует и получает через name/anonymous pipe сборку в виде массива байт, создаёт из неё сборку и выполняет, (3) из главной программы запустить вспомогательную, и передать ей сборку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Вы уже один раз помогли мне два года назад, я хотел компилировать код из textbox, сейчас уже задачи немного другие, вопросы соответственно тоже. Спасибо еще раз вам за ответ, пожалуй единственный человек на этом форуме, от которого получаю мгновенную поддержку.

Comment: Практически все эти два года меня не было на сайте, так что это хорошая случайность. По вашему вопросу: возможно, более лёгким путём будет всё же создать файл где-нибудь под именем `Path.GetTempFileName()` и запустить с диска.

Comment: Так у меня программа сама создает файл, если указать параметр `GenerateExecutable = true`, я здесь могу поменять только путь. По идеи, параметр `GenerateInMemory = true` и подразумевает то, что файл создается в памяти. Но я вот никак не пойму, как мне его из этой памяти запустить, причем таким образом, чтобы образовалась консоль. Я нашел на одном сайте (https://streletzcoder.ru/osnovyi-kompilyatsii-i-vyipolneniya-koda-na-letu-v-c/)
 пример, в котором указывается непонятный мне параметр `CompilerOptions = &quot;/t:library&quot;`, при этом есть скрины консоли, которая исполнила этот код..

Comment: `/t:library` означает, что скомпилируется библиотека (dll), а не exe. Из памяти запустить сложно, я бы не рекомендовал так делать, а таки поставить `GenerateInMemory = false` и запускать с диска.

Comment: Еще один вопрос. Хорошо, будем создавать файл и открывать его через Process.Start. Можно как-то передать аргументы в консоль? 
Я знаю, что во втором параметре Process.Start указываются как раз таки аргументы, которые передаются. Но как мне их принять в компилируемом приложении? Исходный код там очень большой, нет смысла его здесь публиковать, но главный метод в коде - Main. Могу ли я в него передать аргументы или мне воспользоваться другими способами?

Comment: Ну, у метода Main обычно есть аргументы — `string[] args`. Если вы запустите процесс с аргументами, они попадут в `args`.

Comment: Да, я попробовал так сделать. Почему-то не передает полностью строку, а только до пробела... 
Передаю строку one two, а в консоли получаю просто one
//Все, исправил. Строка делится на элементы args через пробел

Comment: Если вам нужно, чтобы где-то по пробелу не резалось (например, это имя файла с пробелом), заключите его в двойные кавычки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126608/discussion-between-varagian-and-vladd).